# JTable changing cells colour's from a given ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

So I have the following class which defines basic parameters of an error

```
public class Error {

public String desc;
public int rowNumber;
public int colNumber;
public int fixNumber;

public Error(String desc,int row, int col, int fix){
    this.desc = desc;
    rowNumber = row++;
    colNumber = col++;
    fixNumber = fix;
}
...
```

My gui Class

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

AbstractTableModel model;
JTable table; 

public void start(AbstractTableModel model) { 
    this.model = model;
    table=new JTable(model){
        @Override 
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) { 
            return false; 
        }

    }; 

    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);


    TableColumn column = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setPreferredWidth(120);  
            column.setMaxWidth(300);
            column.setMinWidth(50);
            column.setCellRenderer(new customCellRender());
        }



        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);  
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,900));
        add(pane); 
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        pack();
        setVisible(true); 
}
```

I have attempted to make a cellRenderer but at the moment it does not have the intended effect. Because it colors all the cells.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class customCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer  {

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean     isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
    Component c = null;
    c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);   
    c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 72, 72));

     return c;
}
```

I then have a List which stores instances of the error class.What I cant figure out is how to ONLY change the color of the cells in my table based on the Error(rowNumber,colNumber). Considering that the errors are in a list structure, so I would have to iterate over and somehow pass each error column and row to the renderer. Is that possible ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

Your code colors all the cells because the component is reused, not recreated every time. Just add a

```
if (error) {
    c.setBackground(errorBackground);
} else {
    c.setBackground(table.getBackground);
}
```

A couple of points to make:

1. Don't create a new Color every time. It's expensive and you're using the same one anyway.
2. Use a Set for your errors to make `contains` quick, otherwise your rendering may become very slow with a large number of those.

Comment: good point but I'm still left with the question of how do I render the table cells that are inside of `List<Error>errors`. So i iterate through each value and pass the row number and column number to ?

Comment: @user1477957 If you insist on using a `List` of errors, that's the best you can get. (Well maybe you can use a spatial index to make it logarithmic instead of linear). However if you had a Point object which has a row and column and a hash&equals functions, you could use a HashSet with constant access (As said in point 2 of the answer)